# Objective C / iOS - Property not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective c and iOS

I'm trying to get a simple method working but I am getting a problem.

declarations and implementations:

WebServiceCall.h

```
 - (void) setwebServiceUrlStr: (NSMutableString *) newUrl;
```

WebServiceCall.m

```
- (void) setwebServiceUrlStr: (NSMutableString *) newUrl
{
   webServiceUrlStr = newUrl;
   NSLog(@"Setting webServiceUrlStr = %@",webServiceUrlStr);
 }
```

In then in WebServiceCall.m I am try to do this:

```
NSString *sUrl = [defaults objectForKey:@"sUrl"];
[self.setwebServiceUrlStr: sUrl];
```

The last line produces the following error:

Property 'setwebServiceUrlStr' not found on object of type 'WebServiceCall'

if I remove the parameter from the declaration , I dont get the error

Comment: Change last line to [self setwebServiceUrlStr: sUrl]; (remove the dot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you only have a method named `setwebServiceUrlStr:`.  You have not declared a property.  To declare a property you would use:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *webServiceUrlStr;
```

Once you have it declared, your setter will be synthesized automatically and you do not need to rewrite it as you have (i.e., you can delete that method now).  The only reason you would override it is if you needed different functionality from the default which sets the corresponding instance variable.

The default setter and getter for a property are: `propertyName` (getter) and `setPropertyName:` (setter).  So to set the property you can either call `[self setPropertyName:var]` *or* use the dot notation which does not include the word "set": `self.propertyName = var`.

So your code would look like:

```
NSString *sUrl = [defaults objectForKey:@"sUrl"];
self.webServiceUrlStr = sUrl;
```

Note: I would recommend not using a mutable string here, and just declaring your property to be an `NSString` instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *webServiceUrlStr;
```

Unless you explicitly need to mutate the property (very rare), you should not make it mutable.

Answer (score -1):

You can not name the property stating with 'new'. as a parameter should be fine.

@sha has pointed out the error.

it should be

```
self.webServiceUrlStr = sUrl;
```

and if you are accessing the property from other class. It should be something like this

```
WebServiceCall *webCall = [[WebServiceCall alloc] init]

   [webCall SetWebServiceUrlStr:sUrl];
    or
    webCall.webServiceUrlStr = sUrl;
```

Comment: This is wrong. `new` only has a special meaning if it is part of the method name, not the parameter name. See sha's comment above for the answer.

Comment: The name of the variable does not matter here.  The issue is that properties are not being used correctly.

Comment: yeah that's right. I miss read read the question. I was thinking about naming the property... as a parameter should be fine. I will change it